# c++ create array of widgets

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio

I need to create an array of TabPage widgets with c++ using Visual-Studio 2015. I will need to be able to insert new TablePage widgets into the array. Does anybody know how I can do this.

thanks.

Comment: Any reason a `std::vector` won't do ?

Comment: Sorry I meant tabpage

Comment: What would be the syntax for std:: vector array?

Comment: when I try to create a vector array in the header file of the class I get the error `a member of a managed class cannot be of a none-managed class type.` how do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, after a some more research I came up with a solution for creating an array of windows form widgets. I was not able to use std::vector or a standard array because I was working in a ref managed class. So I found out that I can create a List like this: `List<System::Windows::Forms::TabPage^> tabPageList;`

Comment: That's not C++, that's Microsoft's C++.Net or whatever it's called.

Comment: Oh OK that makes sense. Thanks